# Tag Cloud for Private Tumblr Blogs?

Tags: html, tags, tumblr, tag-cloud

HTML question: Is there a way to manipulate a *private* Tumblr blog's HTML so that it supports a tag cloud? The only third-party tag cloud widget out [there now](http://tumblrtags.hr1v.com/)  doesn't work with private Tumblr blogs. Help!